How do I copy a unsigned long long to a byte array in c++?
I have code that sets each byte of a byte array m individually from an unsigned long long named i. I want to do it in ONE operation using memcpy. So copy the value of i to m, so that each byte of m, from index 4 to 11, corresponds with a byte from i, which, as an unsigned long long, is eight bytes. So copy each byte from i to m, so that m[4] = first byte of i, m[5] = second byte of i, etc.
I tested this code in the context of some other code, and it is fast. But I want to use memcpy instead of individual assignments to also test the speed of that.
So here is the code:
int thread = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x + 0xeafe7436;
uchar m[12];
uint res[4];
m[0] = (uchar)(thread & 0x000000ff);
m[1] = (uchar)((thread >> 8) & 0x000000ff);
m[2] = (uchar)((thread >> 16) & 0x000000ff);
m[3] = (uchar)((thread >> 24) & 0x000000ff);

for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < 0xffffffffffffffff; i++) {
    m[4] = (uchar)(i & 0x00000000000000ff);
    m[5] = (uchar)((i >> 8) & 0x00000000000000ff);
    m[6] = (uchar)((i >> 16) & 0x00000000000000ff);
    m[7] = (uchar)((i >> 24) & 0x00000000000000ff);
    m[8] = (uchar)((i >> 32) & 0x00000000000000ff);
    m[9] = (uchar)((i >> 40) & 0x00000000000000ff);
    m[10] = (uchar)((i >> 48) & 0x00000000000000ff);
    m[11] = (uchar)((i >> 56) & 0x00000000000000ff);
    md5(m, 12, res);
}

The shifting and bitwise operations, I think, make my code slower then it should be, so I wanted to try to use memcpy to see if that is faster.
I want to copy the value of i to m, sarting at index 4. How would I do this using memcpy? I have looked into other questions but found them confusing and hard to understand and could not do it myself.

You're overthinking this. Understand that unsigned long long and byte array are just essentially memory locations. All you want/need to do is copy the data from one to the other. And then potentially catching endianness issues.
int main() 
{
    unsigned long long value = 0xeafe7436;

    uint8_t m[sizeof(unsigned long long)];
    uint32_t res[sizeof(unsigned long long) / sizeof(uint32_t)] = {};

    std::memcpy(m, &value, sizeof(value));
    std::memcpy(res, &value, sizeof(value));

    // This will reverse the byte order to match the original endianness
    // Discard if not needed.
    // If you're using C or C++ older than 17, you'll need to byte swap with a 
    // for loop
    std::reverse(m, m + sizeof(m));
    
    std::cout << "value: " << std::hex << value;

    std::cout << "\n m Array: ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(m); ++i) 
        std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(m[i]) << " ";

    std::cout << "\n res Array: ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(res) / sizeof(uint32_t); ++i) 
        std::cout << std::hex << res[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}

value: eafe7436
m Array: 0 0 0 0 ea fe 74 36
res Array: eafe7436 0


I got it, thank you! The others probably just didnt know how to do it and kept the conversation elsewhere lol.

If you want your code to be portable, do a search for how to detect endianness programatically.   C++20 and later, it's simple (just #include <bit> and compare std::endian::native with std::endian::big and/or std::endian::small).   Before C++20 (or in C) there's more involved.
